# Replacing infinite values with a finite number in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, infinite

I'm a little new to MATLAB and I am working on a class project. So I have these infinite values in my U matrix which I want to remove and replace with 0. This is part of my code:

```
U(Nt,y)=inv(h(Nt,y).*Atot(Nt,y))+inv(h3(y).*Ain2(y))+Rcond(y)
```

There are lots of inifinite values which I should remove to clear up my graphs. If you need any more information just ask. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `U(isinf(U))=0` to remove the infinite numbers in `U`.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks